Why does electron-phonon interaction narrow the band gap of semiconductors
In first-principles calculations, I found that zero-point renormalization of the band gap caused by electron-phonon coupling is typically negative in semiconductors. I'm wondering if this negative renormalization is a general feature that can be theoretically explained . Additionally, are there any known cases or materials where electron-phonon coupling leads to an increase (rather than a decrease) in the band gap?
